# Will using OFFSET keyword perform efficiently when there are a large number of records like 10 million

Tags: sql-server

Will using the OFFSET be efficient when using with a large number like 10 million? This is the old pubs database by Microsoft.

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[emp_id] AS [emp_id], 
    [Extent1].[fname] AS [fname], 
    [Extent1].[minit] AS [minit], 
    [Extent1].[lname] AS [lname], 
    [Extent1].[job_id] AS [job_id], 
    [Extent1].[job_lvl] AS [job_lvl], 
    [Extent1].[pub_id] AS [pub_id], 
    [Extent1].[hire_date] AS [hire_date]
    FROM [dbo].[employee] AS [Extent1]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[emp_id] ASC
    OFFSET 9999999 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY
```

...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[employee](
    [emp_id] [dbo].[empid] NOT NULL,
    [fname] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [minit] [char](1) NULL,
    [lname] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [job_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [job_lvl] [tinyint] NULL,
    [pub_id] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [hire_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_emp_id] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [emp_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employee] ADD  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [job_id]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employee] ADD  DEFAULT ((10)) FOR [job_lvl]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employee] ADD  DEFAULT ('9952') FOR [pub_id]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employee] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [hire_date]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employee]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([job_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[jobs] ([job_id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employee]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([pub_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[publishers] ([pub_id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employee]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_emp_id] CHECK  (([emp_id] like '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][FM]' OR [emp_id] like '[A-Z]-[A-Z][1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][FM]'))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employee] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_emp_id]
GO
```

Comment: What do you find when you tested this? This is just way too vague. Where is the table definition? What about the indexes? Try running this yourself and look at the execution plan. What do you find?

Comment: If "dbo.employee" is a view or "emp_id" column is not index, it is very possible you will encounter performance issues.  More detail is required.

Comment: And what is the user defined type empid? And why do you not have a clustered index on this table? 10 million rows in a heap is going to be slow no matter what you do.

Comment: As a rule, no, `OFFSET` is not efficient. This is because the engine has to actually find the row with the exact number you gave it, and indexes are only of limited help in this, as those index *values*, not record numbers. On the other hand, there is no real *use case* for an offset of 10 million either -- if you have a paging interface capable of getting to 10 million (as opposed to locating rows in some more effective way), you've got a UI mistake.

Comment: I'm using a console app to iterate through a batch of records at a time (1000 records) until, for example, 10 million records are processed.

Comment: Well, um, don't do that. Either hook up a `SqlDataReader` to get the batches, and never let go until you're done processing everything (which might take a really long time), or get your batches by keeping track of the last `emp_id` you've seen, and do `TOP(1000) ... WHERE emp_id > @mylastempid ORDER BY emp_id`, which can be satisfied with an index seek. `OFFSET` also has the drawback that it will fail to give you a consistent view of the rows if rows are deleted or inserted -- using ID offsets only fails this way if rows are not consistently added at the end.